# locale not found/setting locale failed - what should I do?

Tags: debian, locale

I've installed Debian 7 i386 on my VPS (OpenVZ). Everything works fine, except locales - any attempt to install anything shows:

```
[...]
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "pl_PL.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
[...]
```

What I've tried:

1. Generating locales myself - `update-locale LC_ALL="pl_PL.UTF-8"` - shows: http://www.wklej.org/id/1248438/
2. `apt-get install --reinstall locales` http://www.wklej.org/id/1248442/
3. The same with `dpkg-reconfigure locales` + setting `pl_PL.UTF-8`, `pl_PL.ISO-8859-2` or even `en_US`: http://www.wklej.org/id/1248446/
4. `export LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8` (even on root):

   ```
   -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (pl_PL.UTF-8)
   ```

Here is what shows locale:

```
root:~# locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Nothing interesting found in /var/log. Even changing repo to official + purge and manual installation locales doesn't solve my problem, which manifests itself on each fresh installation of Debian 7.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It seems that no locale is generated. Have you selected `pl_PL.UTF-8` properly in `dpkg-reconfigure locales` by pressing <kbd>space</kbd> in the corresponding line?

If yes, the line

```
pl_PL.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

in `/etc/locale.gen` is not commented (= does not start with `#`). If you need to fix this, you need also to run `locale-gen` to generate the locales. Its output should be:

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
   pl_PL.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

If it does not output the locales you want to generate, there seems to be something wrong with your system. One reason could be that you have `localepurge` installed. If there are no files in `/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES` or `/usr/share/locale/pl_PL/LC_MESSAGES` this is the case or your system is broken.

Comment: It works! Selected position in /etc/locale.gen was still commented, don't know why (yes, I remember about spacebar) - maybe something is wrong with CHMOD. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `-plow` is the default, so can be omitted. You only need to call `dpkg-reconfigure`, which will call locale-gen after you tick the entry you want.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas thanks, I removed it from the answer and clarified the usage of `locale-gen`.

Comment: Another possibility is if you have configured your system etc for en_US but your `/etc/locale.gen` has only uncommented `en_GB`. I noticed this mistake in this thread here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287716/16920 Please, add it to the throubleshoot strategy too.

Answer (score 14):

first:

```
sudo apt-get purge locales
```

then:

```
sudo aptitude install locales
```

and the famous:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

This rids the system of locales, then re-installs locales and downgrades libc6 from 2.19 to 2.13 which is the issue. Then configures locales again.

Comment: Seems to help but the next `apt-get dist-upgrade` will break it again.

Comment: Why would it break it? At that point shouldn't locales be compatible with the libc6 being used? My libc6 was changed to use some other program. I've downgraded it back to the default libc6 version so my system works properly. At which point it should be very much compatible with an apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: An `apt-get install locales` installed the locales on my Docker debian container.

Answer (score 8):

The quick and easy way (although it will mean more disk used than others):

```
apt install locales-all
```

Answer (score 1):

try run

```
locale -a
```

if you got

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

The solution for this situation is to install the package locales (from glibc package [1] ) in debian flavor or glibc-all-langpacks CentOS/Fedora

[1] https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/glibc

Comment: `glibc-locale` package does not exist in Debian

Comment: should be package locale ... fixed