# Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!

Tags: debian, locale, vagrant

**UPDATE**

I found the problem. I need to relog after setting the language variables. But what I'm wondering is: How would I relog inside a vagrant script? Is this even possible?

**Introduction**

I've read about this problem already on other threads

[locale not found/setting locale failed - what should I do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110757/locale-not-found-setting-locale-failed-what-should-i-do)

but it didn't help me really. The accepted answer asked if the line with the desired language is uncommented in `/etc/locale.gen` which it is in my case, but it still doesn't work.

**What I'm trying to achieve**
I'm building a Vagrant box with `debian/jessie64` which should automatically set the language variables to German. I have `locale.gen` file in my vagrant folder which should replace the default one in `/etc/locale.gen` with this command

`sudo cp /var/www/project/www/vagrant_ressources/locale.gen /etc/`

These are the contents of `locale.gen`

```
de_DE ISO-8859-1
de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8
de_DE@euro ISO-8859-15
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Afterwards I'm regenerating the locals with `sudo locale-gen`. This is the output

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  de_DE.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_DE.UTF-8... done
  de_DE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
Generation complete.
```

Now I'm trying to install a package `sudo apt-get install -y php7.0-fpm` and am getting the warning

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Why does `de_DE.UTF-8` come up there? I also want to do this without using `dpkg-reconfigure` because this is a script which should do everything without user input. And `dpkg-reconfigure` simply creates the `locale.gen` file, nothing more, right?

Also, when using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` the entries from my own `locale.gen` file are already selected. So it seems like part of this works.

When typing in `locale -a` these are the results

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE
de_DE@euro
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.iso885915@euro
de_DE.utf8
deutsch
german
POSIX
```

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you seem to have changed `LC_CTYPE` but not `LANG`

Make sure you updated `/etc/default/locale` correctly.  Then you could just `source /etc/default/locale` after running locale-gen.